# How we start an activity in MainActivity which extends AppCompatActivity

Tags: android

I used startActivity() method but it is not working.I think this method is not working because my MainActivity extends app compat actvity.
So please help me to start activity in an app compat activity.
I try various times but when I start my apk and click on button then app crashes.

Here my code

**main.xml**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#E96050"/>


<TableRow><Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/mainButton"
   android:text="Open Second Activity"
   android:onClick="yas"/></TableRow> </TableLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.*;
import android.support.v7.app.*;
import
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.*;


public class MainActivity extends 
AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle 
savedInstanceState)
{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    CreateMenu(menu);
    return true;
}
private void CreateMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0,0,0,"item1");
    {
        mnu1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mnu1.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS); 
    }

}
public void yas(View vv) {
Intent iiii = new 
Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondAct.class);
startActivity(iiii);
}


}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="secondActivity" 
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="SecondActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: pl provide your code.

Comment: NO research !! I think this was the first question asked under android tag.

Comment: @ADM Indeed!. User should search on GOOGLE at first.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you try this code..

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Please add second activity into android manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"/> // define second activity name.
```

add this code in android manifest file..

```
 <activity
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:label="secondActivity" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Check my question now add the code

Comment: i update my answer and also remove this lines in android manifest file ..

Comment: <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="SecondActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

Comment: i update my answer and also make some changes in android manifest file.

Comment: Still app crashes when I click on button

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(this,Target_Activity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

And open your manifest file add this line

```
 <activity android:name=".Target_Activity"

      android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

  </activity>
```